# Merge repeated measurements dataframe in R

Tags: r, merge, dataframe

I would like to merge two dataframe of repeated measurements. Both of them have format like this and the difference is that the first one has observation1 while the other has observation2.

```
Location    Date    Time    observation1
1   1/1/2000    6:00    20
1   1/1/2000    7:00    14
1   1/1/2000    8:00    35
1   1/2/2000    6:00    20
1   1/2/2000    7:00    14
1   1/2/2000    8:00    35
2   1/1/2000    6:00    10
2   1/1/2000    7:00    14
2   1/1/2000    8:00    45
2   1/2/2000    6:00    30
2   1/2/2000    7:00    24
2   1/2/2000    8:00    35
.
.
100 10/31/2000  6:00    80
100 10/31/2000  7:00    80
100 10/31/2000  8:00    80
```

I want to process them so for each location at a specific date and time, the observation1 and observation2 can match up.

I planned to use a for loop to do it, meaning I pick one row from dataframe1, match it with dataframe2, and then pick another row from dataframe1 and do it over and over. But since the dataframes both have several millions of rows, this is super slow.

Can anyone suggest a more efficient way? Thanks!

Comment: `merge(data1,data2,by=c("Location","Date","Time"))`?

Answer (score 0):

Following, @Anrew Taylor
A direct way of doing it is using Merge : a reproducible example is as below:

```
Location = c(1,1,2,3,4,1)
Date1 = c(as.Date("2014-01-01"), as.Date("2000-01-01"), as.Date("2005-01-01"), as.Date("2001-12-01"), as.Date("2001-11-01"), as.Date("2001-10-01"))
Time1 = c(20,30,40,50,60,70)
Observation1 = c(1,2,3,4,5,6)

Date2 = c(as.Date("2014-10-01"), as.Date("2001-01-01"), as.Date("2005-01-01"), as.Date("2001-12-01"), as.Date("2001-11-01"), as.Date("2001-10-01"))
Time2 = c(20,20,40,50,50,70)
Observation2 = c(7,8,9,10,11,12)


data1 = data.frame(Location = Location, Date = Date, Time = Time, Observation1 = Observation1)
data2 = data.frame(Location = Location, Date = Date2, Time = Time2, Observation2 = Observation2)

merge(data1,data2, by = c("Date", "Time", "Location"))
```

That will return :

```
        Date Time Location Observation1 Observation2
1 2001-10-01   70        1            6           12
2 2001-12-01   50        3            4           10
3 2005-01-01   40        2            3            9
```